# How common is the verb "wear down" and what proficiency level does it correspond to?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, verb-usage, frequency

I would like to know how common the phrasal verb "wear somebody down" is in English. Additionally, I'm curious about the proficiency level at which it is usually taught or considered appropriate. For example, is it classified as C1 or C2?

The reason I ask is that I couldn't find this phrasal verb in the book "Oxford Word Skills: Idioms and Phrasal Verbs," neither in the Intermediate nor the Advanced level.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Note: Please feel free to make any modifications to the question as per your preference.

Comment: I'd say it's a relatively colloquial "somewhat idiomatic" usage that probably shouldn't be included *anywhere* in a list of "expressions that are worth addressing in a TEFL context". At the level where it might be appropriate, I think you'd need to know English well enough to (a) - figure out the figurative meaning for yourself, and (b) - understand essentially the same usage expressed as, for example, ***grind** someone down*. Plus related metaphoric usages such as ***sap** someone's strength* or ***drain** them*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it worth learning these kinds of colloquial verbs for speaking? And is there a book or source to learn them?

Comment: Google search: "wear down meaning" - first result: Dictionary Definitions from Oxford Languages - wear down phrasal verb of wear - **overcome someone or something by persistence**. "they wore down their opponents to win the marathon match that lasted more than two hours"

Comment: AliEnt: I think at that level, you shouldn't need to be looking at prepared lists of expressions to learn. Just read as much English text as you can - not necessarily *books*, but at least the advantage with a book is if you find you constantly need to look things up, you can choose to switch to a different book that's easier to understand (you can't really enjoy a book if you have to consult a dictionary every other sentence). If, say, Harry Potter books are too difficult (or just not interesting to you), choose something that better suits your preferences *and* language proficiency.

Comment: ...In an ideal world you'd want to concentrate on *spoken* English. But unless you have native Anglophone speakers on hand to interact with, who don't mind having you struggle with a language barrier, that won't necessarily be very practical. It's much more difficult for a non-Anglophone to follow spoken English in a non-interactive context (listening to the radio, say), because you can't ask for things to be repeated or explained (or even just spoken more clearly).

Comment: It's quite a common phrasal verb. There have been many questions here on ELL about phrasal verbs, I think probably because many of them are idiomatic/figurative in nature, and many don't have a literal meaning that can be easily deduced, and some have multiple meanings that depend on context. They are certainly difficult if you don't already know them. However, they are a very import part of English, especially spoken/colloquial English - it's filled with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common enough phrasal verb, and I'm surprised it's not defined in your Oxford book. I myself would teach that phrasal verb in B1 or B2, but I'm not sure how it's officially classified. In my opinion, it's too common to wait until C1 or C2.

Answer (score 1):

The noun "wear", meaning physical changes from use ("you can see the wear on that item"), and the adverb "worn" (something "looks worn") should be understood by anyone with a basic English vocabulary. People might say that something like a bar of soap, a sole of a shoe, a pencil, etc., "shows wear" or "will wear down" and may eventually "wear out".

However, as asked in the question, the phrase "wear somebody down" is a metaphor. It takes physical wear and applies it to human feelings. Obviously, a person's thinking or beliefs do not experience physical wear. However, a person can experience different feelings from repeated (non-physical) "pressure", in the sense defined in a comment above. This is not that advanced in terms of vocabulary. But it does require more advanced conceptual understanding. If you said to a child, your shoe is worn down, they would likely understand. If you tell a child that work has worn you down, they might not understand a lot about that statement, but they could read your emotions and facial expressions and understand basically, that work has made you tired, or left you "drained" (another metaphor).

This is a long explanation for a basic answer. In American English, from a young age we often hear phrases with "wear down"/"worn down" and generally understand what it means. I think it would be useful for non-English speakers to learn this as an idiomatic phrase, in both the physical and metaphorical senses.